# Dynamically change the height of the textarea element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to *dynamically change* the **height** of the textarea element but my code isn't working as expected.

**What should happen:**

As a new line appears, the textarea's height increases until it reaches its max height.

As you remove lines the textarea's height decreases until it reaches its min height.

**What is happening:**

The height increases as new lines are added but the textarea doesn't behave as expected when removing lines. It decreases much more slowly and doesn't reach the min height.

```js
let textInput = document.querySelector(".text-input");

textInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
  textInput.style.height = 'auto';
  textInput.style.height = textInput.scrollHeight + 'px';
});
```

```css
.text-input {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 250px;
  min-height: 100px;
  resize: vertical;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="text-input"></textarea>
```

**Edit**

from the link posted. A simple fix is to add the following line

```
  textInput.style.height = textInput.scrollHeight + 'px';
```